# How to Add custom button to iPhone keyboard in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uikeyboard

I want to add my customView on click of button which contain images similar to smiley(default button)while editing textField or textView using keyboard. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change default keyboard of Apple. But you can use  inputAccessoryView of the text field, add a UIToolbar to it, and in the toolbar you can add a few buttons you want 
or otherwise you create custom keyboard and then use it.

Comment: but also want to add that images to textview similar to default smiley images added.